# How to copy last three pieces data in an NSMutableArray to another NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios4

In an NSMutableArray I have data like this,

```
    MutableArray1:(
           "22.298166 , 73.165809",
           "22.300598 , 73.167183",
           "22.298101 , 73.166188",
           "22.298128 , 73.166194"
           "22.298130 , 73.166194"
          )
```

I want to copy the last three pieces of data from MutableArray1 to MutableArray2.

Please suggest how I can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`subarrayWithRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange%3a) of `NSArray` like this:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange([mutableArray1 count] - 3, 3);
NSMutableArray *mutableArray2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
                                  [mutableArray1 subarrayWithRange:range]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. I didn't know there is a method like `subarrayWithRange` :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This code will help you

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8", nil];

    NSMutableArray * otherArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i= array.count-3; i<array.count; i++) {
        [otherArray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",otherArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple

Apply while loop

```
int i=1;
while (i<4 && i < [array1 count])
{
    [array2 addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:([array1 count]-i)]];
    i++;
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Why is this upvoted, when it contained multiple errors (and still contains)?

Comment: Missing closing `]` bracket.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=[array1 count] - 4 ; i<[array1 count] ; i++){
    [array2 addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can implement your own custom code.

```
if([yourArray count] > 3)
{
  for (int loop = [yourArray count]; loop >= ([yourArray count]-3) ; loop--)
     [secondArray addObject:[yourArray objectAtIndex:loop-1]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use this
   MutableArray *array = [main_array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(main_array.count-3, main_array.count)];
```

Comment: There is no `MutableArray` class (unless created by OP). Also, this will return an immutable array.

Answer (score 0):

```
[MutableArray2 addObject:[MutableArray1 objectAtIndex:[MutableArray1 count]-1]] ;
[MutableArray2 addObject:[MutableArray1 objectAtIndex:[MutableArray1 count]-2]] ;
[MutableArray2 addObject:[MutableArray1 objectAtIndex:[MutableArray1 count]-3]] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if([yourArray1 count] > 3){

        for (int i=[yourArray1 count] - 4 ; i<[yourArray1 count] ; i++){
          [yourArray2 addObject:[yourArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    else{
        for (int i= 0 ; i<[yourArray1 count] ; i++){
          [yourArray2 addObject:[yourArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
```